# Editable <input> fields in the day cells of a JQuery FullCalendar no longer works

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I inherited an application that was using FullCalendar v1.6.4.

In the FullCalendar, on month view, each day cell contained an "input" field that was completely clickable and editable.

I have since upgraded to FullCalendar v3.9.0. The problem is, the "input" fields are no longer clickable or editable.

Here is my code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     dayRender: function (date, cell) {
          if (!$(cell).hasClass("fc-other-month")) {
               $(cell).append("<div class=Input-outer><input data-date='" + $(cell).attr("data-date") + "' type='number' step='0.25' min='0.25' max='24' onkeyup='SummarySection(this)'  class='calenderControl'/></div>");
          }
     }
});
```

Comment: "upgraded to FullCalendar v3.9.0"...you realise the latest version is 5.3.2? Any specific reason you didn't go with the latest? 3.9 is not really supported or updated any more.

Comment: You need to check the console, there will be a list of problems with the version you are using.

Comment: @JamshaidKamran What makes you say that? Actually there are no issues with the above code which would cause any errors. Actually the code works fine except for the exact issue the OP is reporting (this demo uses 3.10 not 3.9 but it's the same issue): https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/YzWjWbx?editable=true&editors=001

Comment: @ADyson When I inherited the application, I found the v3.9.0 dll already added to the solution, but it wasn't being used. I was concerned about jumping too far ahead version-wise and so decided to try and use v3.9.0